# 40k 8th Edition Unit Customization

Tags: warhammer-40k, variants, custom-game-pieces, edition-comparison

**TLDR**

- Has 40k lost a lot of its customization and character options?
- Are the expected codices supposed to give more options/customization?
- Can I take a unique item or character and modify it for my own use?
- If so, and WYSIWYG still applies, how would I compute costs fairly?
- Would it be fair to just double the cost of the normal version?
- Is this something that I should not be as worried about in actual gameplay and just give them what I can from what exists?
- How many of you use unique characters and how did you build them? (*not sure if this should be a separate question by itself or if there is a better way to phrase or location to ask it*)

First let me mention that although I have been a fan of 40k since I first learned of it back with the release of the third edition and I have purchased every rulebook and at minimum all of the codices for the Space Wolves since; I have only played on tabletop a few times, with the last time being almost a decade ago. Please bear with me as I know some of the rules and changes over the years, but the lore has always interested me more. I know a lot has changed over the years but may be ignorant to the intelligence behind some changes...

That said I am looking to jump back into the gaming aspect with the new edition. With the indices I feel like a lot of the customization options have been lost. My previous "build" of the Inquisitor for my army was an Inquisitor Lord, with a needle pistol, daemon hammer, artificer armor, grimore, a targeter, scourging, etc. and I had even had the chosen to take a specific entourage (astropath, etc.).

And while I do believe that those choices came from the options laid out in an older rulebook I loved that I could grab a bunch of different stuff to put into an independent character.

In the Imperium 2 Index I am looking to update my guy (as with the rest of my army) and I noticed that there is not an option for artificer armor or even to give him a boost as an Inquisitor Lord. His retinue seems to be limited to a host of acolytes, deamonhosts, and (thankfully still) a jokaero...

In the points lists it shows the points values for the 3 custom characters without wargear, but then then the master crafted weapons have 0 points. While the option to use them only exists for those special characters, I would like to use a master crafted power sword stat (it is actually a halberd) for my character. **Would it be fair to just double the cost of the normal version?**

I would like to keep my entire army as close to the rulebook as possible, but I would also like to give my unique guys gear that makes them special. **Is this something that I should not be as worried about in actual gameplay and just give them what I can from what exists?** **How many of you use unique characters and how did you build them?**

Comment: I have been thinking for days of how to ask this question... I think this is about as short and concise as I can get it while at least getting me on the right track for answers... I appreciate anyone who takes the time to read and help.

Comment: This should probably be split up into several questions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Has 40k lost a lot of its customization and character options?

Yes and no. In Matched play your options are much more limited, but in Open, and to a lesser extent Narrative play whatever your opponent agrees to is fine!

> Are the expected codices supposed to give more options/customization?

We hope so, but there isn't any definitive word on this.

> Can I take a unique item or character and modify it for my own use?

Absolutely. When and where you can play with that character will depend on how closely you hew to the Index/Codex and how strict events you go to are. If it's not an organized event, talk to your opponent first, and for anything custom strive for underpowered!

> If so, and WYSIWYG still applies, how would I compute costs fairly?

Something outside the rules probably won't fly in a Matched Play organized event. If you're playing with power, it shouldn't matter too much, but you might want to add a Power point or two to the cost of the unit to compensate.

> Would it be fair to just double the cost of the normal version?

Maybe, maybe not. This is way to situational to answer.

> Is this something that I should not be as worried about in actual gameplay and just give them what I can from what exists?

Probably. If you have a regular gaming group talk to them. If you are planning on going to tournaments stick to the rules

Comment: Score, thank you. I was kinda thinking of asking multiple questions, but I thought that one good answer could keep (the majority of it at least) all together. I finally got a chance to go to my local game store yesterday and he kinda said the same thing. Thanks for taking the time to answer...